# How to set the fqdn on a CentOS server?

Tags: centos, puppet, hostname, fqdn, facter

I set my hostname in the /etc/sysconfig/network file to host.example.com

> HOSTNAME=host.example.com

Fyi, I then issued a reboot on the machine.

I have a problem with Puppet: when I run Facter on this machine, it returns the following information :

> #facter fqdn
>
> host.com

So puppet generates a wrong certificate and so on...

Here is what happens on my host :

> # hostname
>
> host.example.com
>
> # hostname --fqdn
>
> example.com
>
> # hostname -y
>
> (none)
>
> # dnsdomainname
>
> com

I don't understand why Facter is getting the wrong information...
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Add the host to the /etc/hosts file for DNS resolution :

> 10.1.2.3    host.example.com host